# Review queue "edit" link does not display warning messages

Tags: bug, status-completed, editing, suggested-edits, reviewing

When attempting to edit a post from one of the review queues earlier today, it appeared that the "edit" link was non-responsive.

Opening the question outside of the review queue, revealed the following message:

[image]

This makes sense. I had already submitted a few edits, and had reached my max for the day.

However, this helpful warning message **does not** appear when clicking the "edit" link from the review queue screen. Instead, you can click "edit" all day, and nothing happens.

Comment: Looks like this has already been reported on the main Meta site: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298797/editing-a-post-during-review-doesnt-show-an-edit-not-possible-message

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [has been fixed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380969/4751173) on March 6th, 2019:

> Starting with the next build, we'll be showing an error message same way as we do on regular question pages:
>
> > [image]